# Why my One-To-Many field is not persisted in database

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to attach a *File* to an *Article* when saving my Article though a Web Service.

Here is how my *Article* is defined:

```
public class Article : BaseEntity
{
    public string Title
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public File MainPictureFile
    {
        get; set;
    }

    (....)
}
```

The *File* Model is defined like that:

```
public class File
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public File()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Here is how my Web Service is coded:

```
[HttpPut]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
public async Task<ActionResult<Article>> PutArticle([FromBody] Article article)
{
    _dbContext.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ArticleExists(article.ID))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return Ok(article);
}
```

So I'm sending a JSON with a *File* already created before. I just want to attach it. Then I'm using a PUT Http request with a structure like this:

```
{"id":"39e01ca9-f398-4359-8834-6a8e8400dfeb", "title":"Title", "mainPictureFile":{"id":"503047a3-4244-4299-bc18-1a42b564c2ed","name":"bat.jpg"},"position":0}
```

All others fields are working perfectly. Only the mainPictureFile is missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: This is just a hunch but I think it has to do with the file constructor giving a new guid for every instance of the File class.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thank you but I'm not creating a File when updating my Article. I just want to attach it.

Comment: Have you tried this? You are saying that the File exists already right? `_dbContext.Entry(article.MailPictureFile).State = EntityState.Modified;` 
And I assume you've verified that it's been deseriliazed correctly?

Comment: @Topher, it worked apparently!! Please add the answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `_dbContext.Entry(article).State = EntityState.Modified;` use `_dbContext.Update(article);`

Comment: @IvanStoev, it works too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness I'm going to try explain more than just the one line answer.

As you've confirmed, using `_dbContext.Entry(article.MailPictureFile).State = EntityState.Modified;` will work, because you're telling the DbContext to start tracking that object within the `Article`.

If you were retrieving that `Article` object from ef in the sense of a traditional update and not from directly from your webservice you wouldn't have needed to tell Ef to start tracking it.

Another way to avoid this happening by mistake is using the concept of a DTO (data transfer object) which you then map to the object you you've retrieved from your database, like the concept of ViewModels used in traditional MVC. That way EF is already tracking it. You also get the added benefit of validations and using ModelState that way.

As Ivan Stoev says in the comments using `_dbContext.Update(article);` will also work. which is nicer because it's one line vs potentially a line per sub-object as per my original suggestion.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation